# Calculate average invested price without helper columns/tables

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, stock, fifo

This post is really worth a read. Another better verion of this topic is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351891/calculate-avg-price-realized-gain-unrealized-gain-via-udf-using-fifo-method).

If you look at the table below, I am trying to find Avg price at every transaction without adding helper columns. The Average price is correct when the side is **Buy** but shows incorrect Avg price on the **Sell** side for which I am looking for a formula, array formula or UDF for the Avg Price column.

| Date | Side | Qty | Price | Value | Holding | Avg Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jul | Buy | 225 | 10000 | 2250000 | 225 | 10000 |
| 2-Jul | Buy | 75 | 10200 | 765000 | 300 | 10050 |
| 3-Jul | Sell | -150 | 9950 | -1492500 | 150 | **10150** |

The formula I have for **Value** is `=E3*D3`, for **Holding** is `=SUM($D$3:D3)` and for **Avg price** is `=SUMPRODUCT($D$3:D3,$E$3:E3)/SUM($D$3:$D3)` which I dragged downwards. Everything seems to be correct except the last value **10150**. Ideally it should have **10,100** as per FIFO logic given below.

1st order: Quantity = 225 | Price = Rs. 10,000.00

2nd order: Quantity = 75 | Price = Rs. 10,200.00

To calculate the average price, first calculate the value (Quantity x Price). Hence:

1st trade: Rs. 22,50,000.00

2nd trade: Rs. 7,65,000.00

Total quantity = 300

Total value for first two orders : Rs. 30,15,000.00

Divide total value by total quantity:

Rs. 30,15,000.00 ÷ 300 = Rs.10,050.00 (Did it using the `=sumproduct` formula)

---

On 3-Jul, we placed a sell order 150 (out of 300). Price: Rs. 9,950.00

Now the FIFO (first in first out) method will be applied here. The method will check the first trade (on the buy-side). In this case, it is 225. 150 sold stocks will be deducted from 225 (first holding). The balance left of first holding which was 225 earlier will now be 225 - 150 = 75

After FIFO,  the table gets converted like this after deducting the sell quantity. See the first Qty is changed from 225 to 75 because 150 stocks were sold.

| Date | Side | Qty | Price | Value | Holding | Avg Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jul | Buy | 75 | 10000 | 750000 | 75 | 10000 |
| 2-Jul | Buy | 75 | 10200 | 765000 | 150 | **10100** |

**Kindly note:** *In case the sell quantity was more than 225, then it would have moved to the next trade to deduct the remaining quantity.*

Now to get a solution to this, additional helper columns or helper tables are needed which I am looking to eradicate and find for a formula or an array formula or an UDF to calculate the Avg Price. I request excel experts to help me with this problem.

---

One more example what I am trying is given below where the invested price is showing incorrect:

| Date | Side | Qty | Price | Value | Holding | Avg Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jul | Buy | 5 | 10 | 50 | 5 | 10 |
| 2-Jul | Sell | -3 | 17 | -51 | 2 | **-0.5** |
| 3-Jul | Buy | 17 | 3 | 51 | 19 | **2.63** |
| 4-Jul | Sell | -15 | 7.8 | -117 | 4 | **-16.75** |

### Edit

Done after getting a solution from @Tom Sharpe

In order to get the average price, I declared two variables avgRate and sumRate as double and modified the `For Each` code a bit. Please advice if there is an efficient way to do it. Appreciate if this can be converted into an UDF so that I don't have to run the code again and again. Thank you so much for the wonderful solution.

```
For Each bs In queue
    Debug.Print ("qty=" & bs.qty)
    Debug.Print ("rate=" & bs.rate)
    avgRate = avgRate + (bs.qty * bs.rate)
    sumRate = sumRate + bs.qty
    Debug.Print avgRate / sumRate
Next
```

Comment: What would be correct answer and how?

Comment: I think invested price is 3 because, in 2nd transsaction, 3 shares were sold from first buying and later on the 4th transaction, 15 shares were sold out of which 2 were taken at the price of 10 and the remaining were taken at the price of 3. Hence whatever qty is left is bought at 3. I may have not explained it well, explanation of the FIFO (first in first out) method is given in the link that i posted. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Kindly refer to the small EDIT I wrote in my original post. Thank you

Comment: "I have tried few formulas such as sumif, sumproduct, combination of sumif and sumproduct but not getting the correct answer." Share your attempts and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Would this be expected result? `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5,C2:C5)/SUM(C2:C5)` or `=SUM(D2:D5)/SUM(C2:C5)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It will be difficult for me to explain. To keep it simple, can we refer to the link i posted? If I get to know how they calculated 10,100 as invested price after the sell transaction then it will be easier to adopt that solution to my example.

Comment: Have you contacted Upstox about this? https://upstox.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new

Comment: Yes... upstox said, they have shown their calculations and they say that is correct which uses the FIFO method. Further they mentinoed that they do not give support for third party softwares. I have understood their logic and I was trying to replicate that logic in excel for which I am not able to write the formula and that is the reason I came here for help.

Comment: Don't get this - are you asking us to help you to interpret the calculation based upon the link you sent ?  Prefer if you described the method of calculation you're looking for us to assist with within this post as links often break/become invalid - and this would be little value to new users.

Comment: You could work backwards - you have 22 stock, you sold 18 so you have 4 left and use LIFO.

Comment: alright, lets not look at the link I have rephrased my question in the original post and tried to expain how the logic works. Please dont downvote my question as it is my first sincere post to get an answer where I tried a lot.

Comment: @JMP, I have understood the logic of FIFO and LIFO. Its just that I am unable to derive the invested price through one single formula. I am looking for a formula which will give me 3 as the invested price becase the unsold stocks were last bought at that price. I hope I am explaining it properly.

Comment: So you want to find how much you paid for whatever stock you have left after FIFO, and divide this by the number of shares left? How much you sold the stock for is irrelevant here?

Comment: Yes please. May be i was not explaining it properly hence there was a lot of confusion.

Comment: Don't want to cast a cloud over this, but the point seems to me to be that you are looking at a step-by-step algorithm rather than a formula and it's difficult to see how you could implement this without a load of helper columns. If I was trying to do it, I would look at using VBA with a queue to store the number of shares and their price in the order that you bought them so the oldest would come out first.

Comment: Downvoting should be considered by future users (not yourself) as to how useful question is.  You have to admit it's complex and was missing plenty of detail for the rest of us to make up in trying to assist you.

Comment: @JB-007 Yes. I agree the complexity and I admit that complete details were not provided. Sorry about that I feel answer to this question will help not only me but also the future users and therefore I would appreciate for soem sort of assistance in solving this sum.

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, I agree that a step-by-step algo is needed with helper columns to solve this. I asked for a single formula because my excel has too much of data and additional columns would be like having too much of information and visually may not look good to view. Is it possible for me get a VBA or UDF solution here or should start a new question with other excel vba or udf tags? Kindly advice. Thanks

Comment: I think it's probably OK to keep this question (it has attracted 60 views which is quite a lot) and just add a VBA tag. You might consider putting the data in the link into your question as a table as well so people don't have to follow the link. Hopefully I will have a shot at a UDF as I am recovering from a flu virus and it will give me something interesting to do.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thank you for showing interest in my query. I will soon edit the complete question and put the data in link along with my initial table and try to explain it well. Take care of yourself and get well soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK well here  is a test version of a VBA implementation.

Algorithm:

```
If 'buy' transaction, just add to the queue.

If 'sell' transaction (negative quantity)

  Repeat 

    Take as much as possible from earliest transaction

    If more is required, look at next transaction

  until sell amount reduced to zero.
```

---

The program uses a class BuySell so you need to create a class module, rename it to BuySell and include the lines

```
Public rate As Double
Public qty As Double
```

The following goes in a normal module.

---

```
Option Explicit


    Sub FifoTrading()
    
        ' Create the queue
        
        Dim queue As Object
        Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue") 'Create the Queue
        
        ' Declare some variables
        
        Dim bs As Object
        
        Dim qty As Double
        Dim rate As Double
        Dim qtySold As Double
        Dim qtyBought As Double
        Dim qtyRemaining As Double
        Dim rateBought As Double
        Dim i As Long
        
        For i = 2 To 5
        Debug.Print (Cells(i, 3).Value())
        Debug.Print (Cells(i, 4).Value())
        
            rate = Cells(i, 4).Value()
            qty = Cells(i, 3).Value()
            
            If qty > 0 Then
            
                'Buy
                
                Set bs = New BuySell
                
                bs.rate = rate
                bs.qty = qty
                
                queue.Enqueue bs
            
                
            Else
            
                'Sell
            
                qtyRemaining = -qty
                
                'Work through the 'buy' transactions in the queue starting at the oldest.
                
                While qtyRemaining > 0
                
                    If qtyRemaining < queue.peek().qty Then
                    
                    'More than enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so just work out what's left
                    
                        queue.peek().qty = queue.peek().qty - qtyRemaining
                        qtyRemaining = 0
                        
                        
                    ElseIf qtyRemaining = queue.peek().qty Then
                    
                    'Exactly enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so remove from queue
                    
                        Set bs = queue.dequeue()
                        qtyRemaining = 0
                        
                    Else
                    
                    'Not enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so remove from queue and reduce amount of sale remaining
                    
                        Set bs = queue.dequeue()
                        qtyRemaining = qtyRemaining - bs.qty
                        
                    End If
                    
                Wend
                
            End If
            
        Next i
        

        
        For Each bs In queue
            Debug.Print ("qty=" & bs.qty)
            Debug.Print ("rate=" & bs.rate)
        Next

        avRate = 0
        totQty = 0
    
        For Each bs In queue
            avRate = avRate + bs.qty * bs.rate
            totQty = totQty + bs.qty
        Next
    
        avRate = avRate / totQty
    
        Debug.Print ("average=" & avRate)
    
    
    End Sub
```

For the first table, the output is

[image]

so the average rate is 10100.

For the second table, the output is

[image]

so the average rate is 3.

**EDIT**

Here is the UDF version which is called as

```
=avRate(qtyRange,rateRange)
```

---

```
Function avgRate(qtyRange As Range, rateRange As Range)


    ' Create the queue
    
    Dim queue As Object
    Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue") 'Create the Queue
    
    ' Declare some variables
    
    Dim bs As Object
    
    Dim qty As Double
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim qtySold As Double
    Dim qtyBought As Double
    Dim qtyRemaining As Double
    Dim rateBought As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sumRate As Double, totQty As Double
    
    For i = 1 To qtyRange.Cells().Count
    

    
        qty = qtyRange.Cells(i).Value()
        rate = rateRange.Cells(i).Value()
        
        If qty > 0 Then
        
            'Buy
            
            Set bs = New BuySell
            
            bs.rate = rate
            bs.qty = qty
            
            queue.Enqueue bs
        
            
        Else
        
            'Sell
        
            qtyRemaining = -qty
            
            'Work through the 'buy' transactions in the queue starting at the oldest.
            
            While qtyRemaining > 0
            
                If qtyRemaining < queue.peek().qty Then
                
                'More than enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so just work out what's left
                
                    queue.peek().qty = queue.peek().qty - qtyRemaining
                    qtyRemaining = 0
                    
                    
                ElseIf qtyRemaining = queue.peek().qty Then
                
                'Exactly enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so remove from queue
                
                    Set bs = queue.dequeue()
                    qtyRemaining = 0
                    
                Else
                
                'Not enough stocks in this 'buy' to cover the sale so remove from queue and reduce amount of sale remaining
                
                    Set bs = queue.dequeue()
                    qtyRemaining = qtyRemaining - bs.qty
                    
                End If
                
            Wend
            
        End If
        
    Next i

    'Calculate average rate over remaining stocks

    sumRate = 0
    totQty = 0
    
    For Each bs In queue
        sumRate = sumRate + bs.qty * bs.rate
        totQty = totQty + bs.qty
    Next
    
    avgRate = sumRate / totQty
    

    

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for vba. hope you are feeling better now. i am pretty excited to understand the algo. when I tried to run it, it gave me error on line `Set bs = New BuySell` I thought I need to set a reference so I tried to google for systems collection queue and tried to to set a reference to `mscorlib` (C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb), `ms wmi scripting v1.2 lib` & `ms scripting runtime libraries` but nothing seems to be working. Can you pls advice what could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I forgot to say that you need to add a class module for the BuySell class - will add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I would need some time to understand how it is works. I will study the algo and also test this with few more samples and get back to you shortly. Thanks for sparing your precious time.

Comment: It's a pleasure. I can easily change it to a UDF which will be more convenient in due course.

Comment: If that can be done then it will help the community too. Before doing that I may have some queries especially error handling.  I must say that it seems to be a pretty good logic with the collection queue approach which I have never seen before. I am still diving into the code to understand it better. I may have to come back to you soon.

Comment: Upvoting @Sharpe's first stab at proffering a soln based upon LoD provided.

Comment: Thank you! Needs a little more work but hopefully on the right lines.

Comment: Thank you @TomSharpe It was a good learning from the logic you presented. I have edited my original post and posted a small modification to your code to get the average price (which works like `=sumproduct` worksheet function). I would appreciate if you can change it to a UDF. Thanks again.

Comment: UDF added but it does need error checking - e.g. if you try to sell more stocks than you have bought. I must have written the average price code at the same time as you but it is basically the same as yours.

Comment: Looks great! Thank you for your kind assistance. I was looking for a solution to this problem since 2 days and could not get proper help from google search. This solution will help lot other people like me who are into stock, forex, commodity or crypto trading. Hope you have completely recovered now. Be active, lively, healthy and in the pink of health. Cheers !

Comment: Thank you for your good wishes (I'm fine now). I will probably add a bit of checking e.g. for what happens when the queue becomes empty, or it tries to work out the average with no stock left. Suggest that FiFo should appear in the title (or possibly as a tag)  to enable  searching. Also this isn't really my area, but I understand there is a related question in there somewhere about traders of any kind who sell a number of units of stock and want to know how much those units cost them to buy on a FiFo basis. Anyway, I 've enjoyed working with you on this and wish you all the best.

Comment: Hi! came back to check if you worked out on the additional checks. It will be benefitial for all the traders. I came across a similar old thread that went without an answer. I could not give a link of your answer to that it as I do not have enough reputation to comment over there. I also made a copy of your UDF because I wanted to make few changes to it in order to calculate **Realised Profit** (profit booked) & **Unrealized Profit** (profit available in the exchange) which again lot of traders are looking for. But I could not figure out how to do it. Wondering if I shud start a new thread.

Comment: Unrealized profit is easy to calculate. Remaining Qty x Avg Price. Referring to first table, 150 x 10100 = 1515000. The Realized profit in this table is 7500 which is calculated as (First Qty - Sold Qty) x First Price. Here is where I am having difficulty especially when the number of trades are more.

Comment: So in short, I was looking forward for having 3 things. The Invested Avg Price (which the UDF is already giving), Unrealized profit (which can be easily calculated - 1515000). Need to know how to calculate Realised Profit and if all three things can be returned using the same UDF by adding a parameter in the formula. Kindly let me know if you have time to look into it and whether I should start a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kawalpreet I'd be interest in looking at these things to make the UDF more useful, although I'm fairly busy at the moment so won't be able to spend a lot of time on it. Yes, I think you should start a new thread, especially as there are now a lot of comments on this one.

Comment: Thank you @TomSharpe for your reply. I have posted a new thread. I am not at all in a hurry. If possible, do have a look at it. Thanks and have a nice time.