# Creation of an automated P&L Statement for share trading (GS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following fields:
Date    Security    Action  Quantity    Price   Total   Brokerage

There are a number of transactions entered into this eg:

```
Date   Security     Action  Quantity    Price   Total   Brokerage
1/1/20  NAB         Buy       100         $10    $1000   $10
1/2/20  CBA         Buy       200         $20    $4000   $10
1/5/20  NAB         Sell      50          $12    $600    $10
```

What I need to be able to do is 'match' securities for buy and sells (and calc profit/loss, strike rate) and enter them into another sheet eg.

```
Date   Action Date    Action Security Qty Buy$ Sell$ P/L   S/R (win/loss record) 
1/1/20  Buy   1/5/20  Sell     NAB    50  $10   $12  $100   100% (these could added columns once import is completed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to have more detail of how your calculations work and what you have tried so far. Meanwhile, you may be interested in looking at this...it turned out to be a fairly major project and I'm not thinking of replicating it in Google Sheets anytime soon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351891/calculate-avg-price-realized-gain-unrealized-gain-via-udf-using-fifo-method/68379601?noredirect=1#comment121023865_68379601

Comment: Thanks Tom let me have a look at this.... I didnt know whether to go down a QUERY pathway or used a scripting process