# Weighted average when item inventory reaches zero (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet containing transaction data (example image) and ran into a problem with weighted averages. The problem occurs after an item is fully sold/unloaded when it is bought again, the calculation includes the old price information of the items that were previously sold. I would probably need to use a function that "restarts" calculating the weighted average after the position reached zero for a specific item and is bought again at a new price. I do not know how to do this or if this is possible in Excel at all. I would really appreciate any ideas or help!

[image]

Formulas currently used are:

`Col H =SUMIFS($F$2:F2; $D$2:D2; D2)`

`Col I =IF(B2="Buy";SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:C2=C2); --($B$2:B2="Buy");$E$2:E2;$F$2:F2)/SUMIFS($F$2:F2;$C$2:C2;C2;$B$2:B2;B2);" ")`

Comment: It should certainly be possible to restart the calculation if all items for a product were sold, but is there ever a situation where some but not all of the items are sold? That would lead to a more complicated calculation depending on whether you were using the most recent (LIFO) or least recent (FIFO) prices. I looked at the FIFO method a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351891/calculate-avg-price-realized-gain-unrealized-gain-via-udf-using-fifo-method

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
First of all, yes there could be a case where items are partially sold. The way I am thinking, it does not make a difference, if I use a LIFO or FIFO model because I can just calculate with an average price. For example if I had 100 items @10$/item and I sell half of that position it does not matter what the exact buy transactions were, I will be left with 50@10. If I then buy 50@20 that should leave me with 100@15. I get that this is a simplified model and I might be thinking wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use xmatch, you can search back for a previous occurrence of a zero and only include transactions after that:

```
=IF(H2=0,"-",
IFERROR(LET(prevZero,XMATCH(1,(H1:H$1=0)*(C1:C$1=C2),0,-1)+1,
SUMIFS(INDEX(G:G,prevZero):G2,INDEX(C:C,prevZero):C2,C2)/SUMIFS(INDEX(H:H,prevZero):H2,INDEX(C:C,prevZero):C2,C2)),
SUMIFS(G$2:G2,C$2:C2,C2)/H2))
```

[image]

assuming all items are sold in one transaction as in your sample data.

Another way of looking it which agrees with your idea is that for buy transactions:

```
New average = (Previous average * previous number of items on hand + Current price * number of items purchased) / Current number of items on hand
```

while for sell transactions the number of items on hand is updated but the average price is just carried forward.

This actually gives a simpler formula:

```
=IF(H2=0,0,
IFERROR(LET(prevTrans,XMATCH(TRUE,C1:C$1=C2,0,-1),
IF(B2="Sell",INDEX(J:J,prevTrans),(INDEX(H:H,prevTrans)*INDEX(J:J,prevTrans)+G2)/H2)),
E2))
```

[image]

I have added a new item C which ends up with an average price of $15 for the 100 remaining units as required.

Comment: That does exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you very much!