# Weighted Average Price

Tags: google-sheets

Do check the attached sheet.
I want to calculate the correct weighted average price in a portfolio, after selling partially.
I have explained in detailed in the sheet.
Thank you

[sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GfktfucZ96mk5MCC4wZhnMUq-gmjGhOx-2VhXWgNobA/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried weighted average price and sumproduct/sum, both are not working.

Comment: are you always wanting the lowest price to be the one used?

Comment: No. I want to exclude the cost of sold units, in calculating the weighted average.

Comment: Maybe use of  FILTER "sell" and column1. Not sure, how to proceed.

Comment: but the thing is, stocks are fungible, so which one is being sold?

Comment: Agree. not much could be done.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: One approach is shown here - in Excel but should work in Google Sheets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578172/weighted-average-when-item-inventory-reaches-zero-excel

Comment: Or this may be more useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792096/how-to-get-the-average-price-i-paid-for-the-shares-i-own-by-trade-history-in-goo

Comment: @TomSharpe thanks. will check.
exactly same question. I will try that in Google Sheets

Comment: `I have explained in detailed in the sheet.` Your question should stand on its own. Please do not assume that a user must/can/will/should open your sheet in order to better understand your question. This is information that you should include in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz. sure, in future I will include the question in the post.